# Replacing Duplicate Strings in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
Name            Reagent
0   Experiment1 water
1   Experiment1 oil
2   Experiment1 water
3   Experiment1 milk
4   Experiment1 water
5   Experiment1 tea
6   Experiment1 water
7   Experiment1 coffee
8   Experiment2 water
9   Experiment2 coffee
```

I want to replace duplicate names within the same experiment with a differentiator of some sort. In the example only water is duplicated within a given experiment.

e.g

```
   Name         Reagent
0   Experiment1 water1
1   Experiment1 oil
2   Experiment1 water2
3   Experiment1 milk
4   Experiment1 water3
5   Experiment1 tea
6   Experiment1 water4
7   Experiment1 coffee
8   Experiment2 water
9   Experiment2 coffee
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: append all values with the [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as a counter (and replace `0` values with empty strings to ignore each first dupe):

```
df['Reagent'] += df.groupby(['Name','Reagent']).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')
print (df)
          Name Reagent
0  Experiment1   water
1  Experiment1     oil
2  Experiment1  water1
3  Experiment1    milk
4  Experiment1  water2
5  Experiment1     tea
6  Experiment1  water3
7  Experiment1  coffee
8  Experiment2   water
9  Experiment2  coffee
```

If need replace only all dupes by both columns filter rows by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by both columns and add `1`:

```
mask = df.duplicated(['Name','Reagent'], keep=False)
df.loc[mask, 'Reagent'] += df[mask].groupby(['Name','Reagent']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
          Name Reagent
0  Experiment1  water1
1  Experiment1     oil
2  Experiment1  water2
3  Experiment1    milk
4  Experiment1  water3
5  Experiment1     tea
6  Experiment1  water4
7  Experiment1  coffee
8  Experiment2   water
9  Experiment2  coffee
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was quick. Please could you give a brief description of what the line is doing.  How would I put a hypen in between the number?

Comment: @ukemi - Thank you.

Comment: @user11305439 - Sorry, dont see full comment. Use `df['Reagent'] += '-' + df.groupby(['Name','Reagent']).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')`

Comment: @user11305439 - Or `df.loc[mask, 'Reagent'] += '-' + df[mask].groupby(['Name','Reagent']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)`